# Matrix plot using RGB color coding

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix, color

I am looking to plot a line of 250 discrete sites with a specified RGB color value based on the import file values.  The import file has the following format:

[image: import file format]

I want the first element in each row to be the blue color value, and the 2nd element to be the red color value.  For, example, the color of the first site would be (0.8, 0, 0.1) using RGB color.

I am trying to use MatrixPlot with the color function, but I can't seem to get it working. I cant seem to get the color function to line up with each site, and loop through all of the sites.  I have a simple model up and running where the import file is just 1 column of 0,1,2 with 0=white, 1=red,2=blue, and looks like

[image: simple model]

I just can't seem to figure out how to do matrix plot for each site using the RGB value plot based on 2 values.

Comment: Each row of the import file is a site.  So row 1 is site 1, row 2 is site 2, etc

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide some code you have tried thus far together the data (or partial)...

Comment: list = {{0.8, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.9, 
    0.0}, {0.5, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.2}};RGBColor[#] & /@ (Insert[#, 0, 2] & /@ list)

Comment: (0.8, 0, 0.1)  should be (0.1, 0, 0.8),  since RGB={Red,Green,Blue}

Answer (score 2):

With simulated data:

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {n, 250}];
colorrules = Flatten@Table[{i -> (RGBColor[#[[2]], 0, #[[1]]] & /@ data)[[i]]}, 
{i, Length[data]}];
MatrixPlot[{Range[Length@data]}, ColorRules -> colorrules, 
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Jose

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `ColorFunction` to specify color in `MatrixPlot`

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
color[i_] := RGBColor[data[[i, 2]], 0, data[[i, 1]]]
MatrixPlot[{Range@Length@data}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> color ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A matrix of number pairs:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10, 2}];
```

Insert `0` in the middle of each entry:

```
data2 = Apply[{#, 0, #2} &, data, {-2}];
```

Use directly (without having to wrap each entry with `RGBColor`) as input in `Image`:

```
Image[data2, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Or use the combination `Graphics @ Raster@#`:

```
Graphics[Raster[Reverse@data2], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Rows are reversed to get the same picture as the output of `Image`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {250, 2}];

col = # -> (RGBColor[#] & /@ (Insert[#, 0, 2] & /@ list))[[#]] & /@ 
   Range@Length@list;

ArrayPlot[{Range@Length@list}, ColorRules -> col, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

or `MatrixPlot`

```
MatrixPlot[{Range@Length@list}, ColorRules -> col, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]